# EF Code first - add collection to a collection, appropriate usage of skip() and take()

Tags: linq, collections, entity-framework-4

I have something like this:

```
var thread = _forumsDb.Threads
                .Include("Posts")
                .Single(t => t.Id == threadId);
```

Now, when i have a single thread, and a collection of posts within it, i want to count those posts, and then take some amount of them and remove the rest.

```
var count = thread.Posts.Count();
var tmp = thread.Posts.Skip(15).Take(15);
thread.Posts.Clear();
thread.Posts = tmp;
```

But that obviously doesn't work. So, how can i add collection to a collection? Is the `thread.Posts.Clear();` appropriate here, or could i do it better?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Erase all except the 15 from the database or just not read more than 15 from the database or...?

Comment: I want to skip first 15 posts and take next 15 of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to load only the 15 posts from the database you need and to perform only a single database query I would use a projection:

```
var data = _forumsDb.Threads
    .Where(t => t.Id == threadId)
    .Select(t => new
    {
        Thread = t,
        Count = t.Posts.Count(),
        Posts = t.Posts.OrderBy(p => p.SomeProperty).Take(15)
    })
    .Single();

var count = data.Count;
var thread = data.Thread;
```

Note that you need to order by some property if you want to use `Take` and `Skip` with LINQ to Entities. If in doubt just order by the post's `Id`.

If the relationship between `Thread` and `Posts` is one-to-many EF will populate the `thread.Posts` collection automatically with the 15 loaded posts.

Comment: Hm... I did exactly the same thing that you suggested, and now i have under data.Posts == 2 posts (i wanted it to be 2, so it is actually good), data.Count == 3 posts (all i have got at the moment, so that is good too), but under thread.Posts (last line of your code) i have 3 posts! Not sure what went wrong but i'm debugging it and cannot detect any errors. :/

Comment: @ojek: Maybe an effect of lazy loading the full collection? Try to disable lazy loading before the query (`_forumsDb.ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled = false`) and test if you still get 3 entities in the Posts collection.

Comment: Uh, yes, that was the case, but, i am not sure if disabling this is a good approach?

Comment: @ojek: In your specific case I'd say yes, it is a good approach. Keep in mind that you can disable lazy loading *per context instance*. So in the next query you are running with a new context (maybe a new `using` block) lazy loading will be enabled again. Lazy loading will load always *all* entities in a navigation collection, you can't filter with lazy loading. But that's exactly what you need in your example, namely filter only the first 15 elements, but don't fetch all posts. (You could have a thread with 3000 posts which you don't want to load completely.)

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it:

```
var count = thread.Posts.Count();
using (var tmp = thread.Posts.Skip(15).Take(15))
{
  thread.Posts.Clear();
  foreach (var Item in tmp) 
    thread.Posts.Add(Item);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You are skipping all the fifteen records which you are getting. Use below

Replace this

```
var tmp = thread.Posts.Skip(15).Take(15);
```

With

```
var tmp = thread.Posts.Skip(15).Take(30);
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: `new[] {1, 2, 3, 4}.Skip(2).Take(2);` results in `{3, 4}`, not an empty collection.